# visual effect graph unity 2d 2020.3.47f1 not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, visual-effects

I have a problem in unity 2020.3.47f1 where when I implement a visual effect, it doesn't seem to work, in that I still see the orange selectiton outline of the vfx, but the actual particles are invisible. I have tried upgrading my unity version and uninstalling and reinstalling visual effect graph in the package manager, but nothing works. I hope someone can help and thanks in advance.
[image: vfx not showing up with orange selection line working]

[image: vfx graph]

Comment: If you look at the scene while running in 3d does it show there?

Comment: no, it does not show up

Comment: well then it would seem what it is outputting is indeed invisible

Comment: yeah it appears so, but the actual texture i have it assigned to is the default vfx texture, so it should be outputting that.